# Publishing log file to browser in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net, .net, logging, browser, asp.net-core

Is there a ready-made solution in ASP.NET Core for publishing log files in browser? This would help developers/testers since they don't always have access to logs on the server. This would of course need to be disabled in production.

Comment: Which logs are you wanting to publish?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there are any ready-made tools for this type of request (At least not in any of the documentation I have read).

You could use an AJAX call to the server to retrieve the log file contents and then set them to an HTML element of your choice.

```
var url = @Url.Action("GetLogFile", "Controller");

$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: url,
data: logLocation,
success: function(data) {
    $(".result").html(data);    
}
});​

<div class="result"></div>
```

Obviously you can use what ever HTML element you want, as a div isn't the best display option. I haven't tested this code but it gives you the idea.

Hope this helps!